# Third party (almost instant) email notifications for chat messages from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, email, messaging, inbox

Is there a service that currently offers this (that isn't just the 'notification' settings on Facebook - as this is too delayed), OR, what would be the best way to attack this in terms of developing an online service that could provide these updates in almost real time?